# java get screen coordinates for any object

Tags: java, awtrobot

I am trying to use java to get screen coordinates for any object in the DOM.

For example I want to write code to take a button name ()or any object in a web or windows app) and return x, y coords so I can perform mouse actions on that button using java robot.

I dont want to get coords myself because I want it more dynamic so get current coords on the fly pass to robot and interact with object.

any thoughts would be great

Comment: retagged this as javascript instead of java

Comment: @Erick: I don't think it's javascript. He's trying to do screen automation using a java based mouse/keyboard robot. Read the part about "or windows app". Retagged java.

Comment: yes sorry for any confusion. I want to write my own gui style automation tool in Java.  Just starting to poke around at some options.  I would love to have a "find" method that takes object name like "start_button" and searches the dom for it and returns a handle or coords.

Comment: There is no DOM in Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be dynamic, get an object handle instead of a location. Then you can call operations on the object directly.

Comment: well if I could a handle I could get coords.  If I know an element name say a button.  buttonxyz  in Java how would I get a handle to it. Do I need to use system32 calls

Comment: From what I've done system32 is the easiest. But then again I haven't spent much time in this domain, I was just giving a direction you could investigate.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the [`Container`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) hierarchy using `getComponentCount()` and `getComponent()`, invoking `getBounds()` as required. The [*Robot Framework*](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/) project may be of interest, too. For reference, the article [*Painting in AWT and Swing*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html) uses the term *containment hierarchy*, rather than *document object model*.